# Why can't an attachment be renamed in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Why doesn't MS Excel allow renaming an unsaved file while sending it over email?

Let me explain it properly - 
I have a data set copied currently and have to send it over to another person. I opened MS Excel using shortcuts

```
Win+R
Enter "Excel"
Ctrl+V
Choose option to send via email
Enter recipients
Click "Send"
```

Looks something like below -

[image]

Is there anyway I can rename "Book2.xlsx" to say "My_Fruit_Order.xlsx" right from here itself?

Please rectify if I'm being ignorant here. Otherwise, will be glad to see MS implement this thingy.

Comment: As far as I know, nope. Only way is saving the file first with a specific filename, and then e-mail it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rename an attachment that is already attached to an email before sending it.

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/940792/you-cannot-rename-an-attachment-in-an-e-mail-message-in-outlook-before) is the Microsoft Documentation.

To work around this problem, rename the file before you attach it to the e-mail message.

If you would like to achieve it, then there are other addons that you could use like kutools.

Comment: Thanks. I like the "Status" section in the link you provided. :) Probably it's there in their to-do list.

Comment: It could in the future. You can look at the RoadMap to see whats in development.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap